# Inconsistent definition of declared and null (empty) in bash?

Tags: bash

### Introduction

I'm trying to test if a variable is declared, but not assigned a value.

According to [this definition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/281100/176843) (which quotes the POSIX specs) declaring means specifying the type of the variable, while setting means assigning it a value. And null (empty string) is considered a valid value.

### Experiments

Yet **declaring a variable only** also assigns it an empty string:

```
declare var_a
[ -n "${var_a+set}" ] && echo "var_a is set to \"$var_a\""
```

Copy/paste this in your terminal and the output is: `var_a is set to ""`

**Declaring an array without setting it** works as expected based on the definition above:

```
declare -a var_b

[ -n "${var_b+set}" ] && echo "var_b is set to \"$var_b\""
```

This doesn't give any output.

Even **declaring an array with this syntax** doesn't appear to set it:

```
var_c=()
[ -n "${var_c+set}" ] && echo "var_c is set to \"$var_c\""
```

But **setting a variable, then unsetting it again** seems to actually "undeclare" it:

```
declare var_d
[[ $(declare | grep ^var_d) ]] && echo "var_d is declared" || echo "var_d is not declared" # --> declared

var_d=some_value
[[ $(declare | grep ^var_d) ]] && echo "var_d is declared" || echo "var_d is not declared" # --> declared

unset var_d
[[ $(declare | grep ^var_d) ]] && echo "var_d is declared" || echo "var_d is not declared" # --> not declared
```

Here the output of the last statement is: `var_d is not declared`

Lastly, based on these experiments I would expect that **declaring a variable local (in a function)**, then unsetting it, then assigning it again would in effect make it a global variable (since it was "undeclared"):

```
function someFunction() {
    local var_e="some local value"
    unset var_e
    declare var_e="some global value"
}

someFunction
[ -n "${var_e+set}" ] && echo "var_e is set to \"$var_e\"" || echo "var_e is not set"
```

Just to **verify that `declare` and `local` are similar in how they work** (which the [`local` manual](https://ss64.com/bash/local.html) implies by stating that "The option can be any of the options accepted by `declare`"):

```
function anotherFunction() {
    local var_f
    [[ $(declare | grep ^var_f) ]] && echo "var_f is declared" || echo "var_f is not declared" # --> declared

    var_f=some_value
    [[ $(declare | grep ^var_f) ]] && echo "var_f is declared" || echo "var_f is not declared" # --> declared

    unset var_f
    [[ $(declare | grep ^var_f) ]] && echo "var_f is declared" || echo "var_f is not declared" # --> not declared
}

# local can only be used in a function, hence the function call
anotherFunction
```

Here the output of the last statement is: `var_f is not declared`

### Questions

I'm wondering whether my understanding is incomplete, or bash isn't consistent in this area;

1. What is the rationale behind this different behavior of arrays and scalar variables (i.e. scalars are initialized to a value, while arrays are not)?
2. Why does unset actually "undeclare"?
3. What would be the canonical definition for "declared" and "set"?
4. How do I reliably determine if any variable (array or scalar) is declared, but not set?

PS: the code examples above can simply be copy/pasted in a terminal session (all in the same session if you prefer)

Comment: I do NOT see "var_a is set to """ -- are you sure you had a "clean" shell when you did that? One without previous experimentation for $var_a?

Comment: When I open a new tab in macOS's Terminal app and paste the lines of the first example I get `var_a is set to ""` as output; Is that a clean shell, or should I take additional steps to make it clean?

Comment: Actually, when I open a new tab and only paste `[ -n "${var_a+set}" ] && echo "var_a is set to \"$var_a\""` then I don't get the output. So I guess my shell is clean

Comment: When I run `bash --version` I get `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)`, by the way. Perhaps that makes the difference?

Comment: Yes, that's actually the case: when I try this with `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release` it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I do not answer all your questions. However  simply declaring a scalar variable does not assign a value to it:

this will cover the 3 conditions: unset, set but empty, set with value

```
if [[ -n ${foo+unset} ]]; then
    if [[ -n $foo ]]; then
        echo foo is not empty
    else
        echo foo is empty
    fi
else
    echo foo is unset
fi
```

Simply declaring a variable does not give it a value:

```
$ unset foo
$ if [[ -n ${foo+unset} ]]; then if [[ -n $foo ]]; then echo foo is not empty; else echo foo is empty; fi; else echo foo is unset; fi
foo is unset

$ declare foo
$ if [[ -n ${foo+unset} ]]; then if [[ -n $foo ]]; then echo foo is not empty; else echo foo is empty; fi; else echo foo is unset; fi
foo is unset

$ foo=
$ if [[ -n ${foo+unset} ]]; then if [[ -n $foo ]]; then echo foo is not empty; else echo foo is empty; fi; else echo foo is unset; fi
foo is empty

$ foo=x
$ if [[ -n ${foo+unset} ]]; then if [[ -n $foo ]]; then echo foo is not empty; else echo foo is empty; fi; else echo foo is unset; fi
foo is not empty
```

Comment: It turns out that `GNU bash 4.4.12` works as expected, while `GNU bash 3.2.57` (installed by default in macOS Sierra) does not. Thanks for pointing out that the definition is actually correct.

Comment: glenn jackman, your question implicitly answers questions 1-3; Do you also happen to know how to reliably determine if a variable is unset in any bash version? This would also answer question 4.

Comment: *Any* bash version? This is POSIX parameter expansion syntax, and different versions have different behaviour. We're looking at bug fixes, and you don't want to have to code your way around historical bugs. Is the problem you're trying to solve really that sensitive to unset versus set but empty?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that and see your point; It's for a boolean function I use for debugging/troubleshooting and I asked for any bash version (I really meant POSIX compliant) because I don't want to be surprised with unexpected results when I run it on a different machine with a different shell; Since my last comment I realized I could simply add a precondition check at the beginning of the script that fails if it's an untested version, asking to test if first and include the version if working.

Comment: Question 4 doesn't actually have anything to do with whether or not a variable is set. `declare` doesn't create variables; it sets attributes on *names*. `declare -a foo` just sets the array attribute on the name `foo`; `declare bar` doesn't really do anything. The exception is inside a function, where `declare` implicitly makes the name local, the same as if you had used the `local` command.

Comment: @chepner Question 4 asked how to determine if the variable is *declared* though, regardless of whether it was *set*. Thanks for your clarification about the behavior of `declare` inside functions; I didn't know that.

Comment: `declare foo` is effectively a no-op at global scope. The only effect is that that `bash` appears to remember you ran the command. `declare foo; declare -p foo bar` will at least print an equivalent no-op command for `foo`, but complain that `bar` does not exist. I wouldn't consider that declaring a variable, though; aside from being able to affect the output of `declare -p`, I'm not aware of any useful distinction between a name that has been passed to `declare` and one that has not.

Comment: @chepner That's probably right. My use for it turned out to be a moot case too, actually, once I figured out the actual cause of the problem I was debugging. One point I'd like to make is that the name of the command suggests you're actually declaring something though. And Barmar explained in the SO answer I referenced that "'declared' means that you've used declare or typeset to specify the type of the variable". And declaring a variable as an integer does have an effect (although an unexpected one): `declare -i some_int; some_int="abc"; echo $some_int` prints `0`.

Comment: You also answered my intended question 4, by the way :) The `-p` in `declare -p` does just what is needed for that: `declare -p var_g &>/dev/null && echo "var_g is declared"` prints that it was declared, and only after declaring it first with `declare var_g`.